# Which assembly for MySQL Connection for Universal App

Tags: c#, mysql, win-universal-app, mysql-connector

I want to build a connection to a database using the MySQL Connector.  I get a connection with the assembly `MySql.Data.RT.dll` but this was for Win RT. Is this also the right one for a Win 10 Universal app,  or is it better to use one of the .NET 4.5 Framework:

[image]

**My Question is:**

Which assembly to choose for a Windows Universal App ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql connections are happen through

> MySql.Data and 
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient

these two assemblies are most commonly used dll files for any mysql connectivity.

For Example code in C#:

```
    MySqlConnection MYSQLCON;
    MySqlDataAdapter daDataAdapter;
    MySqlCommand MYSQLCmd;
    public MYSQLDataAccess()
    {
        ConnectionStrinG = getMySqlConnectionString();
        MYSQLCON = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionStrinG);
    }
    public string getMySqlConnectionString()
    {
        string CString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyCString"].ToString();  // Connection string from web.config
        string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[CString].ToString();
        return ConStr;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use SQLite.Net-PCL library.
It will add two references

- SQLite.Net
- SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT

You can refer to to this URL
http://igrali.com/2015/05/01/using-sqlite-in-windows-10-universal-apps/

SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.  This package contains an extension SDK and all other components needed to use SQLite for UAP application development with Visual Studio 2015.  Further information, including complete documentation, may be found at the official website http://www.sqlite.org/.

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 RTM and 10240 SDK, there's now the official (no more pre-release stuff) SQLite VSIX package that you can download from SQLite.org. Search for "Universal App Platform" and you're good to go! The rest of the blog post should apply to this version as well.

Comment: Add Further Explain.